# Spring Boot DevTools losing hot swapping and LiveReload features in Grails 4.0.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, grails, spring-security

I am currently working on a Grails 4.0.3 project with the following dependencies:

- spring-boot-devtools
- spring-security-core: 4.0.4
- spring-security-cas:
  4.0.0-SNAPSHOT

When I make changes in my classpath, I observe the typical "File ... changed, recompiling..." message, followed by "Grails application running at https://localhost:8081/myproject" in the development environment. However, every change triggers a reconfiguration of Spring Security Core and CAS, significantly slowing down the development pace. As a result, I have to manually refresh my webpage after each compilation.

```
File D:\Workspace\myproject\grails-app\controllers\TestController.groovy changed, recompiling...

Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core


Configuring Spring Security CAS ...
... finished configuring Spring Security CAS

Grails application running at http://localhost:8081/myproject in environment: development
```

It seems that my project lacks incremental compile features. This behavior is frustrating and can be a major impediment to the development process.

When I remove spring-boot-devtools from dependencies, it doesn't compile any change.

My main concern is why spring-boot-devtools seems to lose hot swapping and LiveReload features. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and if so, what steps can be taken to address this problem and restore a smoother development experience?

Comment: Are you running your app in debug mode? Check the options under 'File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | HotSwap'. What happens if you hit 'Ctrl+F9' (Build | Build Project) after you make the changes?

Comment: @Koyasha tried but the issue is still exist.

Comment: @DashzevegGalbadrakh check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/61361656/2166188

Comment: @Michal_Szulc Thank you very much. It works in Grails 4. Also, I have Grails 5 projects. Do you have any idea how to solve the issue in Grails 5?

Comment: @DashzevegGalbadrakh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74713133/hot-reload-classes-in-grails-5-x